# I will be able to cook

Tags: modal-verbs, future-tense

Here (https://poligo.com/en/articles/grammar/when-use-can-or-be-able-ability) it was written:

> If you mean "**know how to**", use "**can**":
>
> *I can cook*
>
> *Can you speak French?*
>
> There is a difference between these two sentences:
>
> *Can you cook?*
>
> *Are you able to cook?*
>
> If I ask you (1), that means *"Do you know how to cook?"* If I ask you
>   (2), that means *"Do you have time to cook?"* It is asking about your
>   situation, and if it is possible for you to do it.

Then we have a problem which is what does the next thing mean:

**I will be able to cook** ?

It will be taken like:

*I will know how to cook*

or

*I will have time to cook* ?

Comment: Your starting point is false. It's simply not true that *Can you cook?* asks whether you know ***how** to cook, as opposed to *Are you able to cook?* asking whether you have the time and/or inclination to do so. Both constructions can have both senses, though we're more likely to switch ***can*** to ***could*** or ***would*** for the ***are you willing**?* sense.

Comment: Note that without further context, ***I will be able to cook*** tells us nothing at all about whether the speaker currently knows how to cook. But with the slightly different ***I will be able to speak French***, unless there's a rather contrived context, we can be practically certain the speaker ***can't*** currently speak French.

Comment: So, your conclusion is the author of that article is someone who doesn't know Englih if my starting point which I took from that page is false?

Comment: Yes. But by all means post a link tio that "disinformation" site, so we can all lay into it!

Comment: Here it is - https://poligo.com/en/articles/grammar/when-use-can-or-be-able-ability

Comment: I just googled the four quoted strings **"Can you cook" "Are you able to cook" "Do you have time to cook" "Do you have time to cook"**, and got back precisely **three** hits. Two were for that same source you've linked to. The other one is a [wordreference.](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/i-will-be-able-to-cook.3706467/) thread where no-one endorses this spurious distinction.

Answer (score -2):

"I will be able to cook." can mean "I will have time too cook" or "I will be physically capable of cooking," for example.

"I can cook." means "I know how to cook."

Comment: *Now they're easing the lockdown, why don't we have a barbecue today? I can cook and you can entertain our guests.* That's my way of providing an example to show that I don't agree with this semantic distinction. Both forms can carry both senses.

Comment: So, they are completely interchangeable?

Comment: Not really, no. The difference between ***Can you pass the salt**?* and ***Can you understand quantum mechanics**?* is primarily one of CONTEXT. But "conditional" auxiliary verbs like ***can, could, will, would, might,...*** can have a huge range of difference meanings, which native speakers often *deliberately* keep "vague" because people don't always *want* to say exactly what they mean (especially when we're talking about things involving desire, ability and expectation).